# Create Asynchronous client to consume WCF created with SVCutil.exe

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

I have my WCF which only returns a Boolean, has the contract created and within the WCF tests everything works correctly. The problem arises when I create the client and it does not execute the methods asynchronously.

I need to know if there is a way for the methods to run asynchronously.

Is there a way to generate an asynchronous method with the SVCUtil that works?

This is my interface

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IService1
 {
    [OperationContractAttribute]
    bool booleanMethod ();
 }
```

TestWCF.svc class

```
  public class TestWCF: IService1
  {
      public bool BooleanMethod ()
      {
          return BooleanMethod();
      }
  }
```

After this I generate my class with the svcUtil statement in the Developer Command Prompt.

**svcutil.exe http://MyTest//Service.svc?wsdl**

The created file is placed in my Xamarin Project and it works correctly when I use my normal method, but when using the same method asynchronously it gives me an error.

```
  bool Result = Test.BooleanMethod (); // Execute correct

  bool ResultAsync = Test.BooleanMethodAsync (); // It does not execute correctly
```

Can someone help me with the client's asynchronous calls?

Comment: I doubt that `BooleanMethodAsync` returns bool

Comment: What error? What do you mean with *It does not execute correctly*?

Comment: Test.BooleanMethodAsync returns a Task<bool>, not a bool.  So you need to use "await Test.BooleanMethodAsync()" to get the actual bool.